# Android app and "Failed to seed OpenSSL PRNG applyOpenSSLFix"

Tags: android, openssl, google-play

I've received error message from Google about OpenSSL in my APK file. After updating OpenSSL, I execute `unzip -p name.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"` and it resulted in:

```
Failed to seed OpenSSL PRNG applyOpenSSLFix.
```

May be, somebody have same problem, how I can fix that?

P.S. sorry for my English.

Comment: See [Some SecureRandom Thoughts](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html) from the Android Developers Blog.